# Iterate through lines of a file using python starting not at non-zero index

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very surprised I'm not seeing this asked anywhere before. I need to loop through the lines of a text file. But I only care about content starting on say line 3. I'm lost at how I would tell it to ignore index zero & 1 and start recording at 2 (line 3) and beyond

```
complete_path = "C:\\test.txt"
my_array = []

with open(complete_path,"r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    line = 2 # I tried this, obviously I'm completely wrong and it doesn't work

    for line in lines:
        my_array.append(line)
```

Comment: `readlines` creates a list, so you can use `slice` to ignore the first items in the list when you loop over it: `for line in lines[2:]`

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing this was very simple. Thanks to commenter: schwartz

```
complete_path = "C:\\test.txt"
my_array = []

with open(complete_path,"r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines[2:]:
        my_array.append(line)
```